# How to set display multiple data under one perticular field

Tags: php, mysql

This is my sql outcome:[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to show the garden and under that it shows the hose pipe ,lawn moar etc.

How to write the query?

Comment: What you have tried yet? Any queries? What's your expected out?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you would normaly do that somehow like that.

```
cat_id | parent_id | cat_name | cat order
1        0           Garden     1
2        1           Hose Pipe  1
3        1           Lawn Moar  2
```

in this case Garden for example would have the cat_id 1 and parent_id 0 and all subcategories have their own incremented id and the parent_id of garden, which would be 1 in this case!

then you can query for your categories and foreach of them query for the subcategories where the parent_id is the cat_id of the maincategory!

here you have a nice tutorial on how to display it recursive:
https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-category-subcategory-tree-php-mysql/

that way you also only need to save the imagepath only once in your maincat!